# Is there a way to override virtual generic method by replacing some or all of type parameters?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to override virtual generic method by replacing some or all of type parameters with actual type arguments?

```
class A1
{
    public virtual void Generic<T, U>(T t, U u) { }
}

class A2 : A1
{
    public override void Generic<T,int>(T t, int u) { } //error
}
```

thanx

Comment: Is the closing parenthesis in `<T,int)` a typo? Because if not, that could be your error. Also, it would be helpful to know what error you're getting. It would keep me from asking obvious questions, like this one.

Answer (score 7):

Try moving the generic parameters to class.

```
    class A1<T,U>
    {
        public virtual void Generic(T t, U u) { }
    }

    class A2<T> : A1<T , int>
    {      
        public override void  Generic(T t, int u) { }
    }
```

Comment: in other words, we can't override virtual generic method by replacing some or all of type parameters with actual type arguments?

Answer (score 5):

Your example is a little bit ...generic. I am sure that these classes have a meaning of some kind, such that the following architecture makes sense:

```
class A1<U> 
{
    public virtual void Generic<T>(T t, U u) { }
}

class A2 : A1<int>
{
    public override void Generic<T>(T t, int u) { } // no error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have shown, you can do it if the type arguments of your function correspond to type parameters of the class.

If they do not correspond, it's not possible, because your example would violate type safety. Consider the following example:

```
A1 a = new A2();
...
a.Generic<string, string>("", "");
```

It's a legal call, since A1 provides `Generic<T, U>(T t, U u)`. But at runtime, we have a problem, since the dynamic type of `a` is `A2`, and the version in A2 only supports int as the second parameter.